# Can't compile libmmal_core.so on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, raspberry-pi

I'm following [this](http://thinkrpi.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/opencv-and-camera-board-csi/) tutorial to use the RPi camera board with OpenCV, but can't proceed after step three, because of following error:

"No rule to make target /opt/vc/lib/libmmal_core.so needed by camcv."

(camcv is the name of the project/mainfile)

I've configured the CMakeList.txt as described in the tutorial and did all previous steps. Due to another error (compiler couldn't find the file in it's original directory) I've copied the file bcm_host.h into the project directory.
Update/Upgrade of RPi was made yesterday.

Any tips or solutions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us your CMake code.

Comment: crazy question. What do you get when you type ls -l /opt/vc/lib/libmmal_core.so

Comment: the libmmal_core.so is existing. I've solved the problem, because I changed the working directory.

Comment: here is the cmake code:

Comment: http://thinkrpi.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/opencvpi-cam-step-3-create-your-own-project/